# How to set ip of service within a container? static ip in default network

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

With an ip-address of a containerized Elasticsearch from the output of `docker inspect` I succesfully called the [Elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.12.1/api/elasticsearch.html) function in a Jupyter notebook running inside another container. Both are run by `docker compose up`.

But on my end that [ip-address changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066015/reaching-elasticsearch-from-jupyter-notebook/78201834#78201834) at new run-times (e.g. docker compose up/down).

*Is it possible to set the ip?* e.g. by adding something to the the `docker-compose.yml` or the `Dockerfile` of elasticsearch used in the build context?

```
docker inspect *composed-container-name-here*

"NetworkSettings": {
      "Bridge": "",
      ...
      "Ports": {
          "9200/tcp": null,
          "9300/tcp": null
      },
      ...
      "IPAddress": "",
      "Networks": {
          "*composed-container-name-here*_default": {
              "IPAMConfig": null,
              ...
              "Gateway": "172.X.X.1",
              "IPAddress": "172.X.X.3",
          }
```

I tried [subnetting](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/network/create/#specify-advanced-options) in `docker-compose.yml`, but it returned `Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solution](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3739#issuecomment-471247062):

```
services:
  a-service-here:
    ...
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: x.x.x.3 # desired-ip-here

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: x.x.x.0/16 # includes desired-ip
```